# Management studio 2008 debugger does not support 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

When I try to access a 2005 database in studio 2008 I receive the debugger does not support 2005 or earlier.

This is a new install, as far as I understand.  Is there something that I need to turn off to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you press the green play button (debug button) in the query window.  To run the query without debugging, just press the Execute button (or the F5 key).